# jqPlot - x coordinate, timestamp and date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using `jqPlot` with `DateAxisRenderer` to display graphs of various functions of time. I want to make the graph communicate with other modules of the application, that also deal with time data (but not with graphs). To accomplish this, all modules will write and read the same `time` variable (so they always display data for the same instant). If any module sets the variable, the others have to react accordingly.

**Example**: User enters time in a readable format, what causes a custom tick to be displayed in the graph on the proper `x` coordinate.

However, to implement this, I need to convert between three representations of time

- any human-readable format (or the javascript `Date` object as its encapsulation)
- the timestamp used internally by `jqPlot` to represent time
- `x` coordinate (in pixels) in the graph

I know that `DateAxisRenderer` can display the timestamp in a customizable human-readable format, as it does so when it renders the `x-axis`. I know that after clicking in the graph, I get the timestamp in the event information (together with the `x` coordinate). But my question is: How to do these conversions ***explicitly?***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Date <--> human-readable formats

[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) works well for this. For example:

```
var date = Date.parse('February 20th 1973');
var date = Date.parse('next thursday');

// Now let's convert a date into a human-readable string
var dateString = date.toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy');
```

### Date <--> jqPlot timestamp

The timestamp used internally in jqPlot is simply the [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in milliseconds:

```
var exampleTimestamp = 1345671839000;
var date = new Date(exampleTimestamp);

// Now let's convert a date into a timestamp
var jqPlotTimestamp = date.getTime();
```

### Date <--> x coordinate (in pixels)

Assuming your x-axis is linear you can determine the value of a point on the x-axis like this (fill in your own values):

```
var myPlot = jqplot(...);
var xAxis = myPlot.axes.xaxis;

var MARGIN_LEFT = 15; // Pixels from [left edge of chart --> minimum X value]

var pixelRange = 300; // Pixels from [min X value --> max X value]
var timeRange = xAxis.max - xAxis.min;

var time; // This will be our answer in the chart's units
time = xAxis.min + timeRange * (xCoordinate - MARGIN_LEFT) / pixelRange;

var timeInMillis = ... ; // Convert the X-Axis unit of time into millis
var date = new Date(timeInMillis);

// Now let's convert a date into an x coordinate
timeInMillis = date.getTime();
time = ...; // Convert millis into X-Axis unit of time
var x = MARGIN_LEFT + pixelRange * (time - xAxis.min) / timeRange;
```

At the time of writing this post, here is a list of the axis names:

```
['yMidAxis', 'xaxis', 'yaxis', 'x2axis', 'y2axis', 'y3axis', 'y4axis', 'y5axis', 'y6axis', 'y7axis', 'y8axis', 'y9axis'];
```

Comment: I actually thought it was unix timestamp, but the values seemed kinda off... but okay, I'll check again. Then of course, I understand linear interpolation, but how exactly do I get `xAxis.min, xAxis.max` values?

Comment: I'll have some time to look into this tonight, but perhaps the timestamps are millis since the epoch in a specific timezone rather than UTC? Are they all offset by the same amount?

Comment: I checked again and it really is Unix timestamp. I must have messed something up before :) So, do you know how to get the `xAxis` extremal values (as I haven't set them, I let jqPlot choose fitting values automatically).

Comment: Get the X axis like this: `var myPlot = $.jqplot(...); var xAxis = myPlot.axes['xaxis'];`

Comment: Here's a list of the axis names in the latest source code: `var _axisNames = ['yMidAxis', 'xaxis', 'yaxis', 'x2axis', 'y2axis', 'y3axis', 'y4axis', 'y5axis', 'y6axis', 'y7axis', 'y8axis', 'y9axis'];`

Comment: Now I feel a bit stupid for never checking the return value of `$.jqplot`... I just skimmed through the examples, never coming across this.

Comment: Ok then, that's all I wanted to know. Thank you very much! :-) I'll check your bounty as soon as the timelimit allows it.